# iOS constraint equation values

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

[image: From Auto Layout Guide]

I'm trying to find out what the values of the left and right views in a constraint equation are.

Currently this is how I see it.

The origin-point (0,0) in the coordinate system is at the top left.

Therefore views.attribute that are closer to the top and left are smaller.

In the image posted above.
RedView.Leading has a higher value than BlueView.trailing. 
The equation is satisfied because 8 is added to BlueView.trailing.

---

The same would apply to the circled constraint in the image below.
superView.top is less than greyView.top because superView.top is on origin.x .

[image: Auto Layout Guide]

---

My question is are the values relative to the origin point ?

Comment: when you say **values** you are speaking about the `+20.0`?

Comment: Relative to what?! What is your origin point? You're just saying the too edge of the red view....be exactly where the superView's top is, but just 20 more...

Comment: @MarcelT No I'm speaking about RedView.leading and BlueView.trailing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Theory of Relativity in Auto Layout

---

### Short answer:

Yes and no. Actually more no. But most importantly: **It's irrelevant!**

---

### Detailed answer:

Layout attributes are *abstract descriptions* of a view's position and size.

#### Position attributes:

- top
- bottom
- leading
- trailing
- ...

#### Size attributes:

- width
- height

While size attributes can describe an absolute value (e.g. `view.height = 20.0`) position attributes are always *relative* to another position attribute. That's why Apple only shows two views in their example, without any coordinate system. The equation

```
RedView.leading = 1.0 × BlueView.trailing + 8.0
```

states that `RedView`'s leading edge is always 8.0 points to the right of `BlueView`'s trailing edge. The origin of the underlying coordinate system doesn't matter!

Let's say we have a coordinate system ∑<sub>1</sub> with an origin O<sub>1</sub> and let's assume that `BlueView`'s trailing edge is at x = 100 with respect to that origin. This would mean:

```
BlueView.trailing = 100
RedView.leading = 1.0 × 100 + 8.0 = 108
```

Now we look at a different coordinate system ∑<sub>2</sub> with an origin O<sub>2</sub> that's shifted by 20 points to the left, so

- O<sub>2</sub>.x = O<sub>1</sub>.x – 20
- O<sub>2</sub>.y = O<sub>1</sub>.y

In this coordinate system `BlueView`'s trailing edge is at x = 120. So we get:

```
BlueView.trailing = 120
RedView.leading = 1.0 × 120 + 8.0 = 128
```

As you can see the values for the layout attributes `BlueView.trailing` and `RedView.leading` are different in ∑<sub>1</sub> and ∑<sub>2</sub>. However, the horizontal *spacing* between the views is the same

```
RedView.leading – BlueView.trailing = 8
```

in both coordinate systems.

#### And that's the whole point of Auto Layout:

To describe the positions and sizes of views **relative to each other**, rather than using absolute values with respect to a particular coordinate system.

> When I tell you to park your car behind your neighbor's car and leave a 1 meter gap in between, you know what to do, right? Without knowing where the road begins!

It's not important.

---

However – and I guess that's what made you ask the question – the system will need to "tell" the display at some point which pixels to draw for a particular view. And the pixel grid *does* have an absolute origin and a fixed coordinate system.

So eventually, the system will substitute the layout attributes for the outermost view (the window) before solving all the constraint equations. At that point in time your layout attributes *will* be relative to a particular origin (most likely the window's origin in the upper left corner, yes) but it's simply irrelevant!

**Apple may choose any coordinate system they want** (even a coordinate system whose origin is 50 points above the screen) and regardless of that particular system your layout will still look the same with the same set of constraints.

Comment: PS: I recently gave a talk on how the layout system resolves the constraints that's still [available on YouTube](https://youtu.be/xjArhdrqAn8). Maybe it helps you deepen your understanding of layout attributes and anchors if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: That makes sense. I realized that what I was fundamentally asking was is a view's position relative to it's superview's origin point. Which is obviously yes.

I was asking because I was trying to visualize the values of leading and trailing constraints. Doing this made the equation clear to me. 

I understand your point that we don't need to know those values because we constrain views relative to other views i.e (park car behind neighbor's car).

Comment: To summarize the problem equations usually have variables. But it helps to plug in real values for those variables. Yes the variables can have diffrent values as you pointed out and this doesn't fundamentally matter.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you are asking requires knowledge of `Auto Layout`.

`Leading, Trailing, Top, Bottom` and other several constraints are applied w.r.t to the views.

**Example**:

```
RedView.leading = 1.0  x BlueView.trailing + 8.0
```

here, the `leading` constraint of `RedView` is applied w.r.t the `BlueConstraint` `trailing` whatever it is. i.e. `RedView` is placed `8 points` farther than `BlueView` in horizontal direction.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html 
 provides a good knowledge of the auto layout constraints, in what context they are applied and the how the views layout according to them.

Also there are `top layout guide, bottom layout guide, margins` with respect to which you apply constraints to a view.

Read more about `auto layout` to get a clear understanding.

**Edit:**

**Example:**

`BlueView frame`: `(x: 0, y: 0, width: 4, height: 2)`

Now the `BlueView trailing` that we have is: `4`

So now we are setting `RedView leading` as:

```
RedView.leading = 1.0  x BlueView.trailing + 8.0
```

i.e. `RedView.leading = 1.0 x 4 + 8.0 = 12.0`

So now the `frame` of `RedView` is: `(x: 12, y: 0, width: 4, height: 2)`

Also from above equation,

```
BlueView.trailing = RedView.leading - 8.0
```

i.e., `BlueView.trailing = 12.0 - 8.0 = 4.0`

So, the equation is valid for both `RedView` and `BlueView`.

Comment: I do understand constraints my question is about the constraint formula. 
I think I need to reword my question. 

Are the values of `RedView.leading` and `BlueView.trailing` calculated in regards to the origin point. 
I ask this because the constraint formula or equation has to be true i.e equal on both sides. 

I'm pretty sure it is.

Comment: Its not about whether the equation is true/false. Its just that you are assigning a value to { RedView.leading }. And the value is in terms of { trailing } value of { BlueView }.

Comment: That is not what the documentation says "Each constraint represents a single equation. Your goal is to declare a series of equations that has one and only one possible solution.".
An equation by definition must be true. 

A constraint follows an equation and my goal is to fully understand the equation.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check if you can get what I am trying to convey.

Answer (score 1):

No, values are not relative to origin point. Forget about this. 
To position them there must be some additional constraints applied to such attributes of views as:

```
left, right, top, bottom, leading, trailing, width, height, centerX,  centerY, lastBaseline, firstBaseline, leftMargin, rightMargin, topMargin, bottomMargin, leadingMargin, trailingMargin, centerXWithinMargins, centerYWithinMargins.
```

Also in iOS 9 there were added diffrent kind of anchorPoints to make adding constraints easier.

Also Autolayout added localized leading and trailing attributes which position (leading is at left or right side of view) depends on Device Locale.

I would suggest the following equations:
redView.width = 0 + 1 * blueView.width
redView.height = 0 + 1 * blueView.height

redView.leading = 20 + superView.leading
blueView.trailing = -20 + superView.trailing
redView.bottom - blueView.bottom
redView.bottom = superview.bottom - 20

So it does not matter where origin is.